# Como leer el puerto serial (bascula) desde c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un problema al querer leer un puerto serial desde c# (Bascula)

el metodo "DataReceivedHandler" nunca es lanzado

```
private static SerialPort puertoSerial;

    public static void InitSerialInterface(string puerto, int baudios)
    { 
        mySerialPort.PortName = "COM1";
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.Even;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 7;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        mySerialPort.Open();
    }
    //Este metodo nunca es lanzado :(
    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

veo que estas abriendo el puerto pero el evento no es el correcto

```
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mySerialPort_DataReceived);
```

con esta linea indicas que tu evento serial receiver se llama `mySerialPort_DataReceived` y no `DataReceivedHandler`

cambia

```
 private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
```

por

```
 private static void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
```